# Help with frequency multiplying

Tags: frequency, multiplier

I'm generating a 15MHz sinusoidal signal from a Colpitt oscillator that i want to multiply to 90MHz. I'm thinking about doing a triple multiplier and a double multiplier to get the right frequency. What is a fast and easy way to do this using discrete components? I don't have time to purchase any IC's. What non-linear circuit should i use? I read somewhere about using a class C amplifier, and then send it through a band-pass filter to get the desired harmonic frequency, but i can't find any schematic for it.

Answer (score 1):

You want a lot of energy at 90MHz, or 11 nanoSeconds period, or 5.5nS half-period.

Get an EXOR, and place 5.5 nanosecond delay in one path. You will have  5.5 nS output pulses. Put a Q of 10 LC on the output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsJv3S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>